# not currently clicked movieclip comes up as true

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5, tile

```
     private var previousClick = null;

        public static var floor1:Array = new Array();
                floor1[0] = [2,1,1,1,1,1,2];
                floor1[1] = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1];
                floor1[2] = [1,1,1,2,1,1,1];
                floor1[3] = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1];
                floor1[4] = [1,1,1,2,1,1,1];
                floor1[5] = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1];
                floor1[6] = [2,1,1,1,1,1,2];

        public function Main()
                {
                    var tilew:int = 60;
                    var tileh:int = 60;

                    for (var i:int=0; i<floor1.length; i++)
                    {
                        for (var u:int=0; u<floor1[i].length; u++)
                        {
                            var cell:MovieClip = new Tile();
                            cell.gotoAndStop(floor1[i][u]);
                            cell.x = ((u-i)*tileh)+365;
                            cell.y = ((u+i)*tileh/2)+70;
                            addChild(cell);

                            cell.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseclick);
                        }
                    }

    function mouseclick(event:MouseEvent)
                {
                        (event.currentTarget as Tile).outline.gotoAndStop("active");
                        event.currentTarget.cellSelected = true;

                        event.currentTarget.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,mouseclick);


                        if (previousClick !== null){
                             (previousClick as Tile).outline.gotoAndStop(1);
                             event.currentTarget.cellSelected = false;

previousClick.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,mouseclick);
                             trace(previousClick);
                        }
                        previousClick = event.currentTarget;
                        previousClick.cellSelected = true;
}
```

So I have tiles called cells lined up to each other to make a floor. When you click a cell, the outline of that tile glows, indicating that it is currently selected. I have also created a boolean that checks if the current tile is selected. The problem is, the boolean is returning true to a tile that I clicked that isn't the currently selected one, especially the first tile I click when the game starts.

So my question is, how can I get a tile that I clicked that isnt currently selected to not equal true?

Answer (score 0):

I think it caused by overlap.

you may try  cell.y = ((u+i)*tileh)+70;

Comment: Thanks for your help. That seems to move the tiles out of place. I also tried dividing it by 1.8 to get a little space between them, but it moves it too far